# Only any one port in the 4 port usb hub is working

Tags: windows-8, usb-hub

I recently bought a 4 port usb hub. I happened to find that only any one port among the 4 ports are working in my laptop. (i.e. all ports are working but only one at a time)

Brand of my laptop is Acer and its installed with Windows8.

Any solutions please.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "only any one port among the 4 ports are working in my laptop" as it's a little unclear on what the problem is

Comment: Ok. There are 4 ports in the hub which I am connecting with my laptop. All are working individually but not working when connected with multiple devices.

Comment: What sort of device are you using?  What are the power requirements of the device?  Are we talking about USB 2.0 or USB 3.0?  All this information is required to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's an "un-powered"/"self-powered" hub and is [unable to provide enough power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hub#Power) for the power hungry devices you are plugging into it.

You should be able to use it with multiple low-power devices but otherwise you will need a powered hub (you may be able to get away with a [USB "Y-cable"](https://superuser.com/questions/293159/low-voltage-usb-ports-and-usb-external-hdd-problem)) that uses an external power source (wall outlet).

You can also use one of these hubs that is powered by 2 usb ports:
[image]

Comment: Or get a USB Hub that has a separate AC power - cumbersome, but this usually ensures that all USB ports have enough power to run.